# How can I use 58mm filters with the Sony Nex-7?

Tags: filters, filter-diameter, sony-nex

I have 58mm filters, and I found out that the filter size common to the Sony lenses supplied with that camera is 49mm. How can I use the larger filters with my Nex? Would I need a step up ring?

Would it be better to buy 49mm filters instead? Would this affect my photos differently?

Comment: For the question on which approach would be better, it would be helpful to know the type and quality of the filters you have, and what you want to use them for. If they're low quality, you may be best saving the money you'd spend on step-up rings and put that towards the better filters.

Comment: @mattdm - A whole set of step up rings is $13 on Amazon. Any decent CPL filter is going to be over $100. And even if you buy a better correct sized filter, a step up set for a few dollars is a good investment I think.

Comment: Well, that's why I asked what she has already. If it's a cheap filter, $13 towards the nicer one might be a better investment, especially if you're planning to buy 49mm-thread lenses in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Yes a 49mm - 58mm step up ring is what you need. [Here is one](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/98836-REG/General_Brand_49_58_49mm_58m_Step_Up_Ring_Lens.html) at BHPhotoVideo for example. And here are a bunch of results [at amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=49mm%20to%2058mm). I would also consider one of the kits that come with multiple step up rings such as this: [http://www.amazon.com/Fotodiox-Anodized-49-52mm-52-55mm-55-58mm/dp/B001G445Q4/ref=pd_bxgy_p_text_y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001G445Q4)

Comment: is it a good idea to use step up rings rather than buy a 49mm filter set? does it affect the photos differently?

Comment: @Dani For most filters, using a step-up ring vs a natively-sized filter is not going to make a big difference. The primary caveats are you may not be able to attach your lens hood if you have one, and the greater space between the filter and front element _might_ lead to a greater propensity for internal reflections if you're not careful. But it shouldn't affect the performance of the filter itself to any great degree.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to your second question about whether the step up ring would affect picture quality, the answer is that it shouldn't.

- You are putting a larger filter on a smaller lens so it won't obscure the lens in any way.
- The quality of the 58mm filter will be the same as a 49mm filter (assuming the same manufacturer etc.)

If you leave the step up ring attached then there's no effective difference between this and having the correct sized filters. The only advantage of the 49mm filters I can think of is that it would look "cleaner" (but hardly worth the extra cost).